# Restoring subversion from hot-backup.py backup

Tags: svn, backup-restoration

Ive been creating backups of my subversion repository using hot-backup.py.  I've had no problems restoring from these backups in the past.  But today I noticed that my "ABCD" repository is backed up in the following format (latest revision is 1234):

```
ABCD-1234
   - db

ABCD-1234-1
   - README.txt
   - conf
   - dav
   - db
   - format
   - hooks
   - locks
```

Why is my repository backup split over two directories?  If I restore only the "ABCD-1234-1" backup, which seems to be the actual repository, I'm missing a lot of recent code.

Is this standard behavior or was my repository corrupted at some point?

Thanks.